# acorn AST query template literal element

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, acorn

I'm trying to query the following:

```
const t = 'template';
const s = `I'm a ${t}`;
```

Acorn parses the template literal portion as:

```
    {
        "type": "TemplateLiteral",
        "start": 32,
        "end": 53,
        "expressions": [
          {
            "type": "Identifier",
            "start": 50,
            "end": 51,
            "name": "t"
          }
        ],
        "quasis": [
          {
            "type": "TemplateElement",
            "start": 33,
            "end": 48,
            "value": {
              "raw": "I'm a ",
              "cooked": "I'm a "
            },
            "tail": false
          },
          {
            "type": "TemplateElement",
            "start": 52,
            "end": 52,
            "value": {
              "raw": "",
              "cooked": ""
            },
            "tail": true
          }
        ]
      }
```

Let's say I wanted to query this by the `raw` or `cooked` keys of the `value` key of the `TemplateElement`. Since the nested `value` item doesn't have a type I'm a bit lost as to how to target that node by those attributes. How would I write that query using [astq](https://github.com/rse/astq)?